# Proof that the square root of a non-perfect square is irrational

Tags: formal-proofs

Is the reasoning for this proof logically sound?

To show that the square roots of all non perfect squares are irrational, we must first know the definitions of rationality and perfect square.

A number n is said to be rational if it can be expressed as a ratio of two integers, a and b, such that a and b are a ratio of two integers in lowest terms, written as $\frac{a}{b}$. This means that the two integers must be co prime. It's worth noting that for any integer i, i is rational, as it can always be expressed as $\frac{k}{1}$ for k = i.

A number n is said to be a perfect square, if for some integer k $\in \mathbb{Z}$, the number can be expressed such that $n = k^2$.

Suppose we have a number n, and n is not a perfect square, but its square root is rational. Since n is not a perfect square, it cannot be expressed as $k^2$ for any integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, since $\sqrt n$ is rational, it can be expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$ for some integers a and b.

Using this, we get $\sqrt n = \frac{a}{b}$, meaning $n = (\frac{a}{b})^2$, however this is a contradiction since we have already defined n to be a non perfect square, and thus not able to be expressed as $k^2$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This means there is no non perfect square n that exists such that the expression $\frac{a}{b}$ in lowest terms is valid.

Therefore, the square roots of all non perfect squares are irrational.

Comment: I think you need a further restriction.  1/4 has no perfect square root.  But its square root is rational.

Comment: Very true, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

What you wrote is a "non-proof".

You say that $n=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$ is not possible because $n=k^2$ is not possible. Doing this, you just assume $\dfrac{a}{b}$ to be an integer, which make the whole discussion vacuous.

---

Consider $\sqrt2$. It is obvious that it is not a perfect square because $1^2<2$ and $2^2>2$. But what about

$$\left(\frac{577}{408}\right)^2=2.00000\cdots\ ?$$

---

The classical proof relies on the identity $a^2=nb^2$, showing that $a^2$ is a multiple of $b$, so that $a$ has a non-trivial factor in common with $b$.

Comment: You make a very good point there.

Comment: @djackson5790: which one ?

Comment: The comment you made about assuming that $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer. Since I already claimed that as a representation of a ratio of two co prime integers. Because, whereas $\frac{4}{1}$ is equal to an integer, $\frac{1}{4}$ certainly isn't.

Answer (score 2):

//Redone Proof Based On Feedback//

Proof that the square roots of all integers that are *not perfect squares* are *irrational*.

To show that the square roots of all integers that are non perfect squares are irrational, we must first know the definitions of rationality and perfect square.

A number n is said to be rational if it can be expressed as a ratio of two integers, a and b, such that a and b are a ratio of two integers in lowest terms, written as ab. Additionally, the two integers must be *co prime*, meaning the only common factor between them must be the *trivial factor*  1. It's worth noting that for any integer $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $i$ is *rational*, as it can always be expressed as $\frac{k}{1}$ for $k = i$.

An integer $n$ is said to be a perfect square, if for some integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the number can be expressed such that $n=k^2$.

Suppose we have an integer n, and n is not a perfect square, but its square root is rational. Since n is not a perfect square, it cannot be expressed as $k^2$ for any integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, since $\sqrt n$ is rational, it can be expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.

Using this, we get $\sqrt{n} = \frac{a}{b}$, $n = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$, and $nb^2 = a^2$. However, if $a^2 = nb^2$, then $a$ and $b$ cannot be *co prime*, as $a$ has a *non trivial factor* in common with $b$.

Therefore, the square roots of all integers that are not perfect squares are irrational.